# pushState in Android 4.0

Tags: javascript, android, browser-history

When I use JSConsole and type window.history it dosen't contain any method for pushState. So what have happend? Is it removed in Android 4.0 in the default browser or how can I use it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, it is a regression bug, but they don't seem to be very interested in fixing it:

http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=23979 vote for it.

Since most manufacturers usually customize the browser in one or another way, they might implement it themselves. I have however never came across any ICS phone which fully supports the history api. can't say I have been looking though.

EDIT: It has been claimed that it is fixed in 4.0.4, however only in the sense that the methods are there and do what you expect them to do, but the URL bar is not updated.

Comment: To update an old answer, support for the History API has been added in 4.2.0

Answer (score 0):

History API is well supported in Android 2.2 and 2.3, but versions 3 and 4 do not. There is no word on whether it will be put back in.

[read more](http://webdesign.about.com/od/historyapi/a/what-is-history-api.htm)

But I think if you use chrome in Android 4 you can use this feature.

Comment: That is not true. History API is implemented (the methods are available) but **is not** "well supported". For many versions including 4.0.4 it does not update location bar, or does not show back button, or otherwise bugs out in inconsistent state.